# How to get parameter values from endpoint in express node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new in Express so I would like some help. I need to create a router to get some values from an endpoint that will be as follow  (I can't modify the endpoint, it is a requirement)

```
../house/1/us/ny&zipcode=12345
```

I tried

```
router.get("/:id/:country/:state")
```

and I am getting the id, country, and state with req.params
I get
id=1
country=us
and for the value of the state, I get `"ny&zipcode=12345"` but I actually want to get both

state=ny
zipcode=12345

I tried with req.query but it doesn't work or perhaps I am using it incorrectly
Any suggestion? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

## URL Encoding

The first issue (I guess?) in the code I see is that you're using `&` instead of `?` to start the query parameters; we use `&` to separate key value pairs (like `foo=bar&baz=hello`). So, you might want to check that once.

If you change the `&` to a `?`, you can access it using `req.query.<objectName>`.

## Other Solutions

I also just your edit, and for that to work we can work with `/house/:id/:country/:stateAndZip` we need to make a few changes.

I would probably use this approach:

```js
const { stateAndZip } = req.params;
const [ state, zipCode ] = stateAndZip.split( '&' );

// Here, state contains 'ny' and `zipCode` is of the work `zipcode=XXXXX`. 
const [ , formattedZipCode ] = zipCode.split( '=' ); // Or use https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html

// formattedZipCode is XXXXX.
```

There are a few problems with this solution; the first one being that this assumes the `zipcode` is the first argument after `&`. If you want a more generic way of doing it, please let me know.

## A Better Solution

Taking the solution from above and assuming we have an unordered list where `zipcode` can be anywhere, we can do the following:

```js
const qs = require( 'querystring' );

const { stateAndZip } = req.params;
const [ state, queryParams ] = stateAndZip.split( '&' );
const decodedQueryParams = qs.parse( queryParams );

// decodedQueryParams will be an object with the property `zipcode`.
```

One issue here is that we may have an ampersand (`&`) in the URL itself, you can take this solution a step further by assuming that all state names in their abbreviated form are only 2 characters and read till the `&`, and parse out the remaining string using `querystring`.

Comment: This is correct, current url doesn't have the standard syntax. If fixed you can also deestructure the req.query object like so 
```const {zipCode} = req.query```

Comment: Thanks for your possible solution, I understand that the way the endpoint was designed is not the right approach. For some unknown reason, it was designed that way and I need to keep the &, you know, "requirements"

Comment: Ah, not a worry! Try out the two solutions I gave and let me know which one works better. Happy to help! (And trust me, I do understand the "requirements" ;)

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint should be /house/1/us/ny?zipcode=12345 and then req.query.zipcode will have the zipcode value. ? instead of &.

When /house/1/us/ny&zipcode=12345 is used, req.params consider ny&zipcode=12345 as the value for the key state. ? ends the endpoint and begins the query parameters.

Comment: That is the problem, I can't change the way the endpoint is. Someone else designed that way (ny&zipcode=12345) time ago and unfortunately I need to keep it the same way

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, your requirement is a bit strange. However, `expressjs` router's path definition is very elastic (look for `Route paths` section under [official documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)). You can define a route with your pattern like this:

```
/:id/:country/:state&zipcode=:zipcode
```

**Fast testing**

Use [Express Route Tester](http://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/), put `/house/:id/:country/:state&zipcode=:zipcode` in `Route` field and `/house/1/us/ny&zipcode=12345` in `Path` field.

[image]

**Full example**

```
import * as express from 'express';

const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const houseRouter = express.Router();
houseRouter.get("/:id/:country/:state&zipcode=:zipcode", (req) => {
  console.log(req.params);
});
app.use('/house', houseRouter);
app.listen(3000);
```

To test, call `http://localhost:3000/house/1/us/ny&zipcode=12345` from `postman`/browser.

Console would log:

> { id: '1', country: 'us', state: 'ny', zipcode: '12345' }